# The construction "there is" and "be to do"

Tags: sentence-construction

Do they make sense? What do the mean?

> 1 There is good advice to be given to your friend.  (Good advice
> exists which can/will be given to your friend)
>
> 2 There is to be good advice to be given to your friend. (Good advice
> must exist which is supposed to be given to your friend)
>
> 3 There is the man to talk to in that town.
>
> 4 There is to be a man to talk to in that town.

Answer (score 1):

1 There is good advice to be given to your friend. (Good advice exists which can/will be given to your friend) is correct and idiomatic though a bit stiff.
"There is good advice available for your friend." is more fluid.

2 There must be good advice for your friend's situation. Correct but odd.

Unless you 're pointing at him 3 is just odd.
There is a man you should talk to (about this issue) in your town.
(There's a line almost exactly this in Hitchcock's  The 39 Steps)
4 no

Comment: WHy is 4 no? There must be a man to whom one can talk to.

Comment: @user1425 I think the way to get the idea of sentence 4 across is, “There will be a man to talk to,” or maybe “There is a man waiting to talk to you.” “There is to be a man” doesn’t break any formal rule of grammar that I can think of, but it’s not something native speakers ever say.